# Installation issue for school

Tags: qgis, installation, teaching

I'm trying to instrall QGIS to potentially use for a class I will be teaching. However, my IT team said they are unable to install it until...
"The installation page for QGIS states in the Mac installer section, "QGIS is not yet notarized as required by macOS Catalina (10.15) security rules." Codesigning and notarization of apps are required by Westminster's security policy; until the publishers of QGIS submit their app for notarization, we can't approve it for installation on school devices."
Any possible ideas?

Comment: you probably need to pay the QGIS developers to submit it

Comment: I suggest to virtualize windows or Linux (preferable Linux) over the Mac and install it there, virtual environments are even securer than direct installation and the virtual machine can be cloned for use on multiple computers.